# mvc reload page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I would like to force the page to completely reload from a button

```
<input type='submit' value='Reset'/>
```

I am using mvc 3 and jquery mobile and would like to use this from the view.  How can this be accomplished? (or how can this be done from say javascript).  Note: this is using jquery mobile so forcing a page to reload/fresh is bit different.

thanks

Comment: Note also, I do have some page validation going on so obviously as this is a reset i need to disable the page validation and reload.  How could I disable all page validation from javascript? ty

Comment: Are you re-POSTing the page or just simply refreshing it?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(":submit").click(function(){
   window.location.href=window.location.href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are refreshing the page (not re-POSTing it) a call to

```
location.reload();
```

should do the trick.